# Why is my confidence interval for sigma so large in my three-level meta-analysis of means?

Tags: confidence-interval, meta-analysis

I recently ran a three-level meta-analysis of means in R, and the confidence interval for the sigma values in the main analysis and in the moderator analyses are very wide. I am wondering why this may be? I have posted the R Code and output below.

> ##Install Matrix package
> library(Matrix)
> ##Install metafor package (only needed once)
> ##install.packages("metafor")
> library(metafor)

Loading the 'metafor' package (version 3.0-2). For an
introduction to the package please type: help(metafor)

> ##IMPORT DATA AND COMPUTE EFFECT SIZE DATA
> ##Import data saved as a comma separated values (CSV) file
> dataset <-read.csv('/Users/susettemoyers/Desktop/CAR.Analysis.AGG1.Merge.csv', na.strings = "")
> ##calculate r-to-z transformed means and sampling variances
> dataset <- escalc(measure="MN", mi=mi, ni=ni, sdi=sdi, data=dataset)
>
> ##SELECT DATA FOR LOW PA Group
> data <- subset(dataset, outcome=="1")

> ##META-ANALYTIC MODELS
>
> ##MULTI-LEVEL MODEL
>
> ##Estimate the overall effect by fitting an intercept-only model.
> overall <- rma.mv(yi, vi, random = list(~ 1 | effect_size, ~ 1 | study), tdist=

- TRUE, data=data)

> summary(overall, digits=3)

Multivariate Meta-Analysis Model (k = 56; method: REML)

logLik  Deviance       AIC       BIC      AICc
-144.920   289.840   295.840   301.862   296.310

Variance Components:

```
        estim   sqrt  nlvls  fixed       factor
```

sigma^2.1   1.166  1.080     56     no  effect_size
sigma^2.2  11.779  3.432     39     no        study

Test for Heterogeneity:
Q(df = 55) = 3009.366, p-val < .001

Model Results:

estimate     se   tval  df   pval  ci.lb  ci.ub
4.679  0.615  7.604  55  <.001  3.446  5.912  ***

---

Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

> confint(overall)

```
      estimate  ci.lb  ci.ub
```

sigma^2.1   1.1658 0.0000 5.8894
sigma.1     1.0797 0.0000 2.4268

```
      estimate  ci.lb   ci.ub
```

sigma^2.2  11.7794 5.2014 21.0746
sigma.2     3.4321 2.2807  4.5907

> ##Build a two-level model WITHOUT variance attributed to variance at level 1 (i.e.,
> ##the typical within-study sampling variance).
> modelnovarlevel2 <- rma.mv(yi, vi, random = list(~ 1 | effect_size, ~ 1 | study),

- sigma2=c(0,NA), tdist=TRUE, data=data)

> summary(modelnovarlevel2)

Multivariate Meta-Analysis Model (k = 56; method: REML)

logLik   Deviance        AIC        BIC       AICc
-145.7007   291.4014   295.4014   299.4161   295.6322

Variance Components:

```
         estim    sqrt  nlvls  fixed       factor
```

sigma^2.1   0.0000  0.0000     56    yes  effect_size
sigma^2.2  13.0232  3.6088     39     no        study

Test for Heterogeneity:
Q(df = 55) = 3009.3658, p-val < .0001

Model Results:

estimate      se    tval  df    pval   ci.lb   ci.ub
4.6744  0.6214  7.5222  55  <.0001  3.4291  5.9197  ***

---

Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

> confint(modelnovarlevel2)

```
      estimate  ci.lb   ci.ub
```

sigma^2.2  13.0232 8.1280 22.1572
sigma.2     3.6088 2.8510  4.7071

> ##Perform a likelihood-ratio-test to determine the significance of variance
> ##attributed to effect sizes within studies (within-study variance).
> anova(overall,modelnovarlevel2)

```
    df      AIC      BIC     AICc    logLik    LRT   pval        QE
```

Full     3 295.8397 301.8617 296.3103 -144.9199               3009.3658
Reduced  2 295.4014 299.4161 295.6322 -145.7007 1.5617 0.2114 3009.3658

> ##Build a two-level model WITHOUT variance attributed to differences between
> ##effect sizes within studies at level 2 (i.e., within-study variance) -
> ##should be identical to a standard "two level" RE meta-analysis.
> modelnovarlevel3 <- rma.mv(yi, vi, random = list(~ 1 | effect_size, ~ 1 | study),

- sigma2=c(NA,0), tdist=TRUE, data=data)

> summary(modelnovarlevel3)

Multivariate Meta-Analysis Model (k = 56; method: REML)

logLik   Deviance        AIC        BIC       AICc
-148.6993   297.3986   301.3986   305.4132   301.6293

Variance Components:

```
         estim    sqrt  nlvls  fixed       factor
```

sigma^2.1  10.7674  3.2814     56     no  effect_size
sigma^2.2   0.0000  0.0000     39    yes        study

Test for Heterogeneity:
Q(df = 55) = 3009.3658, p-val < .0001

Model Results:

estimate      se    tval  df    pval   ci.lb   ci.ub
4.5596  0.4838  9.4255  55  <.0001  3.5902  5.5291  ***

---

Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

> confint(modelnovarlevel3)

```
      estimate  ci.lb   ci.ub
```

sigma^2.1  10.7674 7.1239 16.9082
sigma.1     3.2814 2.6691  4.1120

> ##Perform a likelihood-ratio-test to determine the
> ##significance of the within-study sampling variance.
> anova(overall,modelnovarlevel3)

```
    df      AIC      BIC     AICc    logLik    LRT   pval        QE
```

Full     3 295.8397 301.8617 296.3103 -144.9199               3009.3658
Reduced  2 301.3986 305.4132 301.6293 -148.6993 7.5589 0.0060 3009.3658

> ##DISTRIBUTION OF VARIANCE OVER 3 LEVELS OF META-ANALYTIC MODEL
>
> ## Determining how the total variance is distributed over the three levels of the
>
> ## meta-analytic model based on Cheung's (2014) formula (formula 14 on page 2015);
>
> ## Print the results as percentages on screen.
>
> n <- length(data$yi)
> > list.inverse.variances <- 1 / (data$vi)
> sum.inverse.variances <- sum(list.inverse.variances)
> squared.sum.inverse.variances <- (sum.inverse.variances) ^ 2
> list.inverse.variances.square <- 1 / (data$vi^2)
> > sum.inverse.variances.square <-
> + sum(list.inverse.variances.square)
> > numerator <- (n - 1) * sum.inverse.variances
> > denominator <- squared.sum.inverse.variances -
> + sum.inverse.variances.square
> > 
> > estimated.sampling.variance <- numerator / denominator
> > 
> > I2_1 <- (estimated.sampling.variance) / (overall$sigma2[1]

- - overall$sigma2[2] + estimated.sampling.variance)
    > 
    > I2_2 <- (overall$sigma2[1]) / (overall$sigma2[1]
    + + overall$sigma2[2] + estimated.sampling.variance)

> I2_3 <- (overall$sigma2[2]) / (overall$sigma2[1]

- - overall$sigma2[2] + estimated.sampling.variance)

> amountvariancelevel1 <- I2_1 * 100
> amountvariancelevel2 <- I2_2 * 100
> amountvariancelevel3 <- I2_3 * 100
> amountvariancelevel1
> [1] 0.7389952
> amountvariancelevel2
> [1] 8.939069
> amountvariancelevel3
> [1] 90.32194
>
> ##STANDARD META-ANALYSIS MODELS
>
> ##Estimate standard random effects ("two-level") meta-analysis.
> standardre <- rma(yi, vi, data=data, method="REML")
> standardre

Random-Effects Model (k = 56; tau^2 estimator: REML)

tau^2 (estimated amount of total heterogeneity): 10.7674 (SE = 2.4389)
tau (square root of estimated tau^2 value):      3.2814
I^2 (total heterogeneity / total variability):   99.11%
H^2 (total variability / sampling variability):  112.72

Test for Heterogeneity:
Q(df = 55) = 3009.3658, p-val < .0001

Model Results:

estimate      se    zval    pval   ci.lb   ci.ub
4.5596  0.4838  9.4255  <.0001  3.6115  5.5078  ***

---

Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

> ##Compute CI for tau tau2 I2 and H2
> confint(standardre)

```
   estimate   ci.lb    ci.ub
```

tau^2   10.7674  6.7813  16.3022
tau      3.2814  2.6041   4.0376
I^2(%)  99.1129 98.5987  99.4123
H^2    112.7227 71.3621 170.1508

> ##Estimate standard fixed effects meta-analysis.
> standardfe <- rma(yi, vi, data=data, method="FE")
> standardfe

Fixed-Effects Model (k = 56)

I^2 (total heterogeneity / total variability):   98.17%
H^2 (total variability / sampling variability):  54.72

Test for Heterogeneity:
Q(df = 55) = 3009.3658, p-val < .0001

Model Results:

estimate      se     zval    pval   ci.lb   ci.ub
0.2467  0.0198  12.4753  <.0001  0.2079  0.2854  ***

---

Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

> ##CATEGORICAL MODERATOR ANALYSES FOR HIGH PA
>
> ##MODERATOR ANALYSIS, MODERATOR: AGE
>
> ##Moderator = older
> mod1a <- rma.mv(yi, vi, random = list(~ 1 | effect_size, ~ 1 | study), tdist=

- TRUE, data=data, subset = (age=="1"))

> mod1a

Multivariate Meta-Analysis Model (k = 16; method: REML)

Variance Components:

```
         estim    sqrt  nlvls  fixed       factor
```

sigma^2.1   0.0000  0.0001     16     no  effect_size
sigma^2.2  15.9721  3.9965     13     no        study

Test for Heterogeneity:
Q(df = 15) = 269.4980, p-val < .0001

Model Results:

estimate      se    tval  df    pval   ci.lb   ci.ub
4.8256  1.1544  4.1802  15  0.0008  2.3651  7.2862  ***

---

Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

> confint(mod1a)

```
      estimate  ci.lb  ci.ub
```

sigma^2.1   0.0000 0.0000 5.0267
sigma.1     0.0001 0.0000 2.2420

```
      estimate  ci.lb   ci.ub
```

sigma^2.2  15.9721 7.4115 41.6396
sigma.2     3.9965 2.7224  6.4529

Comment: I am afraid this is almost unreadable as you did not quite manage to get all the formatting right. Can you edit it to improve it? As a comment on your problem have you tried looking at the profile likelihood to see whether you have enough data to estimate $\sigma$ well?